# How to get deleted records with where condition from salesforce?

Tags: rest-api

```
/services/data/{version}/sobjects/{sObjectName}/deleted/?start={start}&end={end}
```

any chance to get deleted records with where clause from this API?
Like I want to get deleted records whoever have phone numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "deleted" resource is a replication API. Instead, you want to use the [queryAll](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_queryall.htm) method:

```
/services/data/queryAll?q=SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE AND ...
```

(Please remember to URL-encode the query string).